# XNA GameComponent.Initialize() not called

Tags: xna

I have a game which creates an object in its Initialize() method:

```
    private GameComponent1 _thingy;
    protected override void Initialize() //Game1.Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
        _thing = new GameComponent1(this);
    }
```

In the GameComponent1 class:

```
    public GameComponent1(Game1 game) : base(game)
    {
        _game = game;
        game.Components.Add(this);
    }

    public override void Initialize() //GameComponent1.Initialize()
    {
        //Do stuff here
        base.Initialize();
    }
```

However, in this case, `_thing`'s `Initialize` method is not called. Why is this?

It behaves fine when the object is created in, say, Game1's `Update` method...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

swap the order of this:

```
base.Initialize();
_thing = new GameComponent1(this);
```

to this:

```
_thing = new GameComponent1(this);
base.Initialize();
```

You need to initialize your components before, I believe.

Comment: Ah, silly me... How could I have missed this? /facedesk